# Relaciones definidas incorrectamente no permiten usar Eager Loading

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Sucede lo siguiente: en mi proyecto Laravel existe un modelo `Facturacion` y otro modelo `Facturacion_Items` (este ultimo viene a ser el detalle del modelo `Facturacion`). Como es de intuir, una factura tiene varios detalles, por lo que la relacion entre ambos modelos es oneToMany. En el caso de `Facturacion_Item` el campo que lo relaciona con `Facturacion` se denomina `FIT_Factura` (ambos son del mismo tipo en la BD).
A su vez, el detalle de cada factura, es decir, cada registro de `Facturacion_Item` esta relacionado con otros modelos del mismo proyecto.

Muestro parte del código de ambos modelos para que se vea con mas precisión:

Modelo `Facturacion`

```php
class Facturacion extends Model
{
   protected $primaryKey = 'FAC_NroFactura';

   //Atributos del modelo que se corresponden con la BD.

   //Funciones relacionales a otros modelos
   public function facturacion_items(){
        return $this->hasMany(Facturacion_Item::class, 'FIT_Factura', 'FAC_NroFactura');
    }
}
```

Modelo `Facturacion_Item`

```php
class Facturacion_Item extends Model
{
    //No posee clave primaria
    //Atributos del modelo que se corresponden con la BD.

    //Funciones relacionales
    public function clinica() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Clinica::class, 'FIT_Clinica', 'CLI_ID')->select(['CLI_ID',
                    'CLI_Descripcion',
                    'CLI_RazonSocial',
                    'CLI_Domicilio'
                    //Otros campos
                   ]);
    }

    public function factura() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Facturacion::class, 'FIT_Factura','FAC_NroFactura');
    }

    public function prestador() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Prestador::class, 'FIT_Prestador', 'PRE_ID')->select([
                    'PRE_ID',
                    'PRE_Codigo',
                    'PRE_TipoDoc',
                    'PRE_NroDoc',
                    'PRE_Apellido',
                    'PRE_Nombre'
                    //Otros campos
                    ]);
    }

    public function tipoPrestacion() {
        return $this->belongsTo(TipoPrestacion::class, 'FIT_TipoPrestacion', 'TPR_ID');
    }

    public function subTipoPrestacion() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Subprestacion::class, 'FIT_SubTipoPrestacion', 'STP_ID');
    }
}
```

Las relaciones entre los modelos están ultra revisadas, así que diría que son correctas (Puede que también este equivocado).

**El problema es el siguiente: a la hora de requerir un detalle de una factura completo (con todas las relaciones), es decir, acceder a través de un objeto de tipo `Facturacion_Item` y serializar el mismo a JSON, no se levantan los objetos relacionados tanto de `Facturacion` como de `TipoPrestacion`, los cuales tienen claves de tipo String y Char(1) respectivamente (se que no es lo mas conveniente este tipo de claves, pero el proyecto es heredado), pero el resto de los componentes si se serializan.**

Muestro los JSON de salida para que me entiendan:

```
{
    "FIT_Factura": "000100008762",
    "FIT_TipoPrestacion": "I",
    "FIT_NumTipoPrest": 1,
    "FIT_SubTipoPrestacion": 1,
    "FIT_Clinica": 157,
    "FIT_Prestador": null,
    "FIT_NroFactura": null,
    "clinica": {
      "CLI_ID": 157,
      "CLI_Descripcion": "I.M.O",
      "CLI_RazonSocial": "INSTITUTO MODELO DE OTORRINOLARINGOLOGIA",
      "CLI_Domicilio": "9 DE JULIO 153 (ESTE)",
      "CLI_Telefono1": "0264-4223392"
    },
    "factura": null,
    "prestador": null,
    "tipo_prestacion": null,
    "sub_tipo_prestacion": {
      "STP_ID": 1,
      "STP_Descripcion": "PR\u00c1CTICAS AMBULATORIAS",
      "STP_TipoPrestacion": "A",
      "STP_IDUsuario": "Admin",
      "STP_FechaUltMod": "2018-07-31 00:00:00",
      "STP_Habilitado": 0
    }
  }
```

Sin embargo, si obtengo la colección de registros de tipo `Facturacion_Items` e itero en la misma puedo acceder a la Factura relacionada, de la misma manera que en el caso de `TipoPrestacion`.

Muestro código de Controller:

```
public function facturacion_item(){
        $items= Facturacion_Item::where('FIT_Factura','=','000100008762')->get();

        foreach ($items as $item)
        {
            dd($item->factura()->get()->toJson());
        }
        return $items;
    }
```

Muestro respuesta:

```
[
  {
    "FAC_NroFactura": 100008762,
    "FAC_ObraSocial": 41,
    "FAC_Plan": 0,
    //Resumido....
  }
]
```

Desconozco por que no puedo obtener los objetos relacionados mediante una llave string cuando requiero levantar toda la colección de objetos `Facturacion_Items`.
No entiendo que estoy realizando mal, pero he invertido mucho tiempo e investigado muchas cosas sin llegar a una solución.
Espero me puedan ayudar....

Agrego una aclaracion, para no caer quizas en algo que he averiguado previamente.
Este es el codigo bajo el cual obtengo el JSON sin los objetos relacionados por string/char.

```php
public function facturacion_item(){
        $items= Facturacion_Item::where('FIT_Factura','=','000100008762')
                ->with('clinica')
                ->with('factura')
                ->with('prestador')
                ->with('tipoPrestacion')
                ->with('subTipoPrestacion')->get();
        return $items;
    }
```

JSON de respuesta

```
{
    "FIT_Factura": "000100008762",
    "FIT_TipoPrestacion": "I",
    "FIT_NumTipoPrest": 1,
    "FIT_SubTipoPrestacion": 1,
    "FIT_Clinica": 157,
    "FIT_Prestador": null,
    "FIT_NroFactura": null,
    "clinica": {
      "CLI_ID": 157,
      "CLI_Descripcion": "I.M.O",
      "CLI_RazonSocial": "INSTITUTO MODELO DE OTORRINOLARINGOLOGIA",
      "CLI_Domicilio": "9 DE JULIO 153 (ESTE)",
      "CLI_Telefono1": "0264-4223392"
    },
    "factura": null,
    "prestador": null,
    "tipo_prestacion": null,
    "sub_tipo_prestacion": {
      "STP_ID": 1,
      "STP_Descripcion": "PR\u00c1CTICAS AMBULATORIAS",
      "STP_TipoPrestacion": "A",
      "STP_IDUsuario": "Admin",
      "STP_FechaUltMod": "2018-07-31 00:00:00",
      "STP_Habilitado": 0
    }
  }
```

Agrego las respectivas relaciones de los modelos que no están pudiendo ser levantados:

Modelo `Facturacion`

```php
public function facturacion_items(){
        return $this->hasMany(Facturacion_Item::class, 'FIT_Factura', 'FAC_NroFactura');
    }
```

Modelo `TipoPrestacion`

```php
public function facturacion_items(){
        return $this->hasMany(Facturacion_Item::class,'FIT_TipoPrestacion','TPR_ID');
    }
```

El resto de las relaciones ya se pueden ver anteriormente.

Agredeceria si me pueden ayudar....

Comment: Es posible que las relaciones estén mal definidas entonces, realmente no habría ningún otro motivo para que no funcione.

Comment: En el json que está al final de la pregunta se puede ver que sí carga la relación **sub_tipo_prestacion**, lo cual indica que las demás están mal definidas.

Comment: Ahí están el resto de las relaciones, entiendo que es básico, también lo he utilizado en otros modelos, pero este me ha complicado.

Answer (score 0):

Lo común y sugerido por la documentación en estos casos es cargar la relación antes de trabajar con dicha información, para evitar el problema N+1. Para esto, Laravel tiene la funcionalidad de Eager Loading, la cual podrías utilizar al momento de hacer la consulta (recomendado) o después.

En el método with() incluye como parámetro la o las relaciones (por el nombre con el que fueron definidas) que deseas cargar:

```
$items = Facturacion_Item::where('FIT_Factura', '000100008762')
             ->with('factura')
             ->get();
```

De esta forma quedaría cargada la factura a la cual pertenece dicho item.

```
$items->factura
```

Ten en cuenta que la estoy llamando como una propiedad y no como función, puesto que las relaciones cargan como propiedades dinámicas, si usas la función estás llamando a la relación desde el modelo (algo así como el Query builder).

Para convertirlo a json simplemente  usas el método toJson() después de realizar la consulta:

```
$items->toJson();
```

Comment: gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responder, La verdad que he abreviado un poco el codigo del controlador por el cual estoy tratando de acceder a la informacion, pero ya he descartado el uso del metodo `with`, debido a que no surte efecto.

Comment: ¿Eh? puedes explicar por qué no surte efecto

Comment: public function facturacion_item(){
        $items= Facturacion_Item::where('FIT_Factura','=','000100008762')
->('clinica')
->with('factura')
->with('prestador')
->with('tipoPrestacion')
->with('subTipoPrestacion')->get();
        return $items;
    }
Ese el codigo del controlador

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no funciona con with? yo te garantizo que with funciona y bastante bien, lo utilizo en todos los proyectos.

Comment: Ahi agregue el codigo del controlador que origina el JSON, por ello digo que no surte efecto

Comment: Realmente esto es muy sencillo y básico en Laravel, **acabo de probar mi ejemplo y funciona**, por favor revisa todo lo que te puse en la respuesta.

Comment: Lamento decirte que tu respuesta no me funciona, no se si son las relaciones, ahí las incorpore a la pregunta, pero me da un error de existencia de la propiedad **factura**, ya que no esta levantando `factura`.
Estoy utilizando lo mismo en otros metodos, pero aun no puedo solucionar el problema.
Gracias de todos modos

Comment: No funciona porque están mal definidas las relaciones, ya lo expliqué.

Comment: Podrias mostrarme entonces como has construido las relaciones?